# filter a list using a lambda that raises exceptions

Tags: python, exception, filter

Using `psutil` I get a list of processes; I want to filter out those with a particular name.

```
filter(lambda p: p.name()=="x", psutil.process_iter())
```

However, the `psutil.Process.name()` function may throw...  in that case `filter` gets the blow, and re-raises the exception to me.

Is there a `filter_noexception` kind of function/idiom, or do I need to wrap `p.name()` into an exception-swallowing function myself?

Comment: What do you want to happen when the exception is thrown?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `p.name == "x"` ( Since `psutil.Process` has `name` as a str attribute ) ?
And since in your case every Process instance will have a name attribute, why would it throw an error ? ( Correct me if I am wrong ) ...

Comment: @rvraghav93: correcting: `name` is a function.  http://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.Process.name

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: good question: I want that entry to be filtered out, as if the predicate returned `False`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this :

```
def try_get_name(process_instance):
    try:
        return process_instance.name()
    except:
        return ""


filter(lambda p: try_get_name(p)=="x", psutil.process_iter())
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a `replace_exception` function decorator:

```
def replace_exception(original, default=None):
   def safe(*args, **kwargs):
       try:
          return original(*args, **kwargs)
       except:
          return default
   return safe
```

And now I can 'safeify' my function:

```
filter(replace_exception(lambda p: p.name()=="x"), psutil.process_iter())
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such handling in `filter` but as [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) says:

> Note that filter(function, iterable) is equivalent to [item for item
>   in iterable if function(item)] if function is not None

With this in mind I would handle processes myself:

```
def filter_noexception(func, iter):
    result = []
    for i in iter:
        try:
            if func():
                result.append(i)
        except:
            pass
    return result

filtered_processes = filter_noexception(lambda p: p.name() == "x", psutil.process_iter())
```

Comment: Thanks - this obviously works, but is not usable in other contexts like `itertools.ifilter` or `map`.  It _would_ be usable if you replaced building up `result` by making it a generator: replace `result.append(i)` by `yield i`